# Find specific key value in array of objects using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, lodash

We have a JSON object like

```
var jsons = {
    "LAPTOP": [{
        "productId": "123"
    }],
    "DESKTOP": [{
        "productId": "456"
    }],
    "MOUSE": [{
        "productId": "789"
    }, {
        "productId": "012"
    }],
    "KEY-BOARD": [{
        "productId": "345"
    }]
}
```

if we search `{ "productId": "012" }` it should return key DESKTOP
It would be great if we can use lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using lodash:

```
let result = _(jsons)
    .pickBy(item => _.some(item, {productId: '123'}))
    .keys()
    .head();
```

First we find the key where the value contains and object with the matching productId. We then take the first key from the collection of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var jsons = {
"LAPTOP": [{
    "productId": "123"
}],
"DESKTOP": [{
    "productId": "456"
}],
"MOUSE": [{
    "productId": "789"
}, {
    "productId": "012"
}],
"KEY-BOARD": [{
    "productId": "345"
}]};

var result = Object.keys(jsons).find((key) => {
    return jsons[key].find((item) => item.productId === '123')
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I vote this cause its optimized and wont do unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 0):

without LODASH you can  have something like this

```
var toSearch = 789;
Object.keys(jsons).forEach((key) => {
  if(jsons[key].find((pid) => pid.productId == toSearch)){
    console.log(key)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsons = {
"LAPTOP": [{
    "productId": "123"
}],
"DESKTOP": [{
    "productId": "456"
}],
"MOUSE": [{
    "productId": "789"
}, {
    "productId": "012"
}],
"KEY-BOARD": [{
    "productId": "345"
}]
};

var id = "789";
for(item in jsons){
  jsons[item].forEach(function(data){
    if(data.productId == id){
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `key in object` for loop syntax like so:

```js
var jsons = {
"LAPTOP": [{
    "productId": "123"
}],
"DESKTOP": [{
    "productId": "456"
}],
"MOUSE": [{
    "productId": "789"
}],
"KEY-BOARD": [{
    "productId": "345"
}]};

var searchFor = "789";

for(var key in jsons) 
  if(jsons.hasOwnProperty(key))
    if(jsons[key][0] && jsons[key][0].productId === searchFor)
      alert(key); // MOUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keys` and `find`.

```js
var jsons = { "LAPTOP": [{ "productId": "123" }], "DESKTOP": [{ "productId": "456" }], "MOUSE": [{ "productId": "789" }, { "productId": "012" }], "KEY-BOARD": [{ "productId": "345" }] },
    value = { "productId": "012" };

var result = _.find(_.keys(jsons), key => _.find(jsons[key], value));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful once you wrap your head around it.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const search = (term, input) => {
  const r = objectScan(['**.productId'], {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'key',
    filterFn: ({ value }) => value === term
  })(input);
  return r === undefined ? r : r[0];
};

const jsons = { LAPTOP: [{ productId: '123' }], DESKTOP: [{ productId: '456' }], MOUSE: [{ productId: '789' }, { productId: '012' }], 'KEY-BOARD': [{ productId: '345' }] };

console.log(search('012', jsons));
// => MOUSE
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)